# PGFplots: Print groupplots over multiple pages

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

For this MWE, I have 8 plots where only 6 are printed where the last two are overlooked. So, is there a way to make PGFplots split the groupplots over multiple pages based on the size of the plot/page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group name=G,
    group size=2 by 3,
}, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty
]
\nextgroupplot[title=1]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
%
\nextgroupplot[title=2]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
%
\nextgroupplot[title=3]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
%
\nextgroupplot[title=4]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
%
\nextgroupplot[title=5]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
%
\nextgroupplot[title=6]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
%
\nextgroupplot[title=7,colorbar horizontal,]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
%
\nextgroupplot[title=8]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit

For this MWE, how to protect the longtable and prevent it from being discontinued by another content such as another exemplary figure here?

Additionally, how to make the caption of the longtable be treated as that of the figure in order to not have conflicts of figures with the same numbers?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{my group style/.style={title style = {at={(0.5,1)}, above}
, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty}}
\begin{document}

%\lipsum[1] 
\captionsetup[longtable]{name=Figure}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
\endfoot
\caption{A table that pretends to be a figure.}\label{fig:ManyPlots}
\endlastfoot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=1] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=2] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=3] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=4] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=5] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=6] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=7] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=8] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{longtable}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh WOW, I'm really impressed by the impact of [@percusse's answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7772/can-tikz-pgf-experts-be-lenient-with-the-existence-of-mwe) ... (just kidding ;-) but +1

Comment: @marmot `XD` improvise, adapt, overcome X))

Comment: Are you aware that the plots get swallowed because of `group size=2 by 3,` (instead of `group size=2 by 4,`)? I am not saying that will make the plots fit, rather I think you need to do two group plots, either 2 by 3 and 2 by 1 or two times 2 by 2.

Comment: @marmot I really forget that but still, the last two were swallowed, which made me look for a clever way to make all the plots be printed smoothly over multiple pages without having to worry about the size of the plot/page.

Comment: @marmot I clearly understand your point. I googled this question but found nothing similar, which made me think that it might be possible. Anyway, I will keep the question hoping that someday it can get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is at best an emergency proposal. However, I do not think that it is straightforward to split a `tikzpicture` over more than one pages, and the current version of group plots is within a `tikzpicture`. One can, however, resort to a package from the previous millennium: `longtable`. (<s>Note that I was not able to use `\captionof{figure}{...}` in the caption of a `longtable`, guess that would be a separate question.</s> Solved, big thanks to Alan Munn!) This will take care of the page breaks and if you define styles for the universal things then the additional effort in typing is not too bad. **EDIT**: Hope to have cured the counter problem mentioned in the updated version of the question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{my group style/.style={title style = {at={(0.5,1)}, above}
, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty}}
\begin{document}

%\lipsum[1] 
\captionsetup[longtable]{name=Figure}
\captionlistentry[figure]{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
\endfoot
%\captionsetup{type=figure}
\caption[figure]{A table that pretends to be a figure.}\label{fig:ManyPlots}
\endlastfoot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=1] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=2] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=3] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=4] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=5] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=6] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=7] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}& 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my group style,title=8] 
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{longtable}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\captionof` requires either the `caption` package or simply the `capt-of` package, I think.

Comment: Actually I think with `longtable` you just use regular `\caption` and it turns it into a mulicolumn entry automatically. No `caption` package needed.

Comment: @AlanMunn Sometimes one only has to listen to the linguists and do a `texdoc caption`. ;-) **THANKS!**

Comment: @marmot Sorry for the long silence since I was away from the PC. Thanks for your answer, and kindly, take a look at my question edit to see if it can be handled.

Comment: @Diaa Yes, the counter issue was clearly a bug. As for the second issue, this is a general issues with floats: they float. There is an endless discussion about this in the forum, and I am probably the least competent source of information on that. Personally I would just issue a `\clearpage` after the `longtable` or change the option of the second figure to `[b]`.